# is there a relu layer(with alpha) for the model in keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I'm making a model in keras and I want to add the alpha variable to the relu layer in my model. is there any way for this problem?

```
from keras.layers import Conv2D, Input, Add, Dense, BatchNormalization, Convolution2D,\
Activation
from keras.models import Model

kernel = 3

img_input = Input(shape=(height, width, 1))
# block 1
x = Conv2D(64, (kernel, kernel), padding="same"
                       , name="block1_conv1")(img_input)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.ReLU(max_value=None, negative_slope=0.1, threshold=0)(x)
```

I used the activation layer to make the relu layer so I don't know how to add alpha or negative_slope to the layer. i saw [here](https://keras.io/api/layers/activation_layers/relu/) and [here](https://keras.io/api/layers/activations/).

Comment: Apart from that, what's the issue of using `tf.keras.layers.ReLU(max_value=None, negative_slope=0, threshold=0, **kwargs)`??

Comment: i try this code in my model but i can not add. how do i add it to this model? the layers is difference. i dont know how i fix my code.

Comment: I post a possible solution, please check.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, with `alpha = 0.1`.

```
img_input = Input(shape=(height, width, 3))
# block 1
x = Conv2D(filter_base, (kernel, kernel), padding="same", kernel_initializer='he_normal'
                       , name="block1_conv1")(img_input)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.ReLU(max_value=None, negative_slope=0.1, threshold=0)(x)
```

Comment: thank you, i have AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'layer'. what is the problem?

Comment: Can you post your full model definition?

Comment: In your full model definition, there is no issue with such a 'tuple` object that has no attribute layers stuff.  Check with `model.summary()` or `plot_model(model)`, it will show you the results. The issue probably you're facing is different, and not relevant to this.

Comment: probably mixing the functions from keras and tf.keras is not allowed until the function is used on lamda layer.